# Non-alphabetic installation order for npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am upgrading my system from npm 6 to npm 8.  As I tested projects with deeper dependency trees I noticed installations would fail.  I eventually discovered the cause is due to the order that npm will install dependencies.  npm 8 and 9 will install dependencies in alphabetic order instead of dependency order as npm 6 and yarn do.

Here is a test scenario.  I created seven packages with various dependencies on each other.  Here is the dependency tree at the top level (proj).

```
> npm list --depth=2

@myscope/proj@1.0.1 C:\src\proj
+-- @myscope/x-1@1.0.1
| `-- @myscope/y-1@1.0.1 deduped
+-- @myscope/x-2@1.0.1
| +-- @myscope/y-1@1.0.1 deduped
| `-- @myscope/z-3@1.0.1 deduped
+-- @myscope/y-1@1.0.1
| +-- @myscope/z-1@1.0.1
| `-- @myscope/z-2@1.0.1
`-- @myscope/z-3@1.0.1
```

package.json is similar for all packages in this test.  Here is package.json for "x-2":

```
{
  "name": "@myscope/x-2",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "echo INSTALL x-2 start&&ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >NUL&&echo INSTALL x-2 end"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@myscope/y-1": "^1.0.1",
    "@myscope/z-3": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

The install script echos the start of script execution, delays for 5 seconds to emulate compilation, and then echos the end of script execution.

When I run `npm i` for "proj" the installation order will vary:

- For npm 6 the installation order is: z-1, z-2, y-1, z-3, x-1, x-2, proj
- For yarn the installation order is: z-1, z-2, z-3, y-1, x-1, x-2, proj
- For npm 8/9 the installation order is: x-1, x-2, y-1, z-1, z-2, z-3, proj

This is clearly not a problem for most people using npm because I cannot find any other posts discussing this issue.  I use npm for mixed language development including compilation of C++ source that depend on object files and libraries generated by their dependencies.  I don't want to switch to a different package management because npm has been serving my needs for more than five years.  I hope I'm just missing something such as a flag which will allow npm to install in dependency order.